# How to: Get order of tabs, save into NSUserDefaults then retrieve

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, nsuserdefaults, uitabbaritem

I have a default UITabBarApplication with default views and tabs... etc. I have eight tabs that have the customizable option, so users can reorder tabs.

How do I get the order of the tabs, save that into NSUserDefaults and retrieve it when the app loads back up. I'd like to see some code examples.

Here is where I'm at so far:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
     Called when the application is about to terminate.
     See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
     */
    NSMutableArray *vcArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:8];
    NSArray *savedViews = tabBarController.viewControllers;
    for (UIViewController *theVC in savedViews){
        [vcArray addObject:theVC.title];
    }

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:vcArray forKey:@"tabLayout"];
}


- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didEndCustomizingItems:(NSArray *)items changed:(BOOL)changed {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSArray *tabLayout = [defaults arrayForKey:@"tabLayout"];
    NSMutableArray *orderedLayout = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:8];
    NSArray *defaultOrder = tabBarController.viewControllers;

    for (int i =0; i < 8; i++){
        for (UIViewController *theVC in defaultOrder) {
            if ([theVC.title isEqualToString:[tabLayout objectAtIndex:i]]) {
                [orderedLayout addObject:theVC];
            }
        }
    }

    tabBarController.viewControllers = orderedLayout;
}
```

This code doesn't seem to work in the simulator. I reorder the tabs and hit done then stop the app, but when I hit build and run again the app reverts to default. Why isn't the code above working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One comment:

`NSUserDefaults` don't always work with the simulator. If you're doing a new build each time, then of course everything gets reset.

Two suggestions:

1. put an `NSLog` in the latter method to make sure that it's being called
2. build the app to a device, move the tabs around, close the app (completely -- not just in background), open the app again, behold what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've put NSLog in the didEndCustomizingItems method and from the bottom debugger console, it doesn't get outputted.

I built it on my device and still it doesn't save the order. Could it be that the didEndCustomizingItems method isn't being called?

Comment: @TheHAWK: If the log statement never appears on the console, then the method is never being called.

Comment: I've just realized that. :) But, when I add the same NSLog to the applicationDidFinishLaunching method it gets outputting to the console. So why is this method not getting called?

Comment: @TheHAWK: You must not have set up the `UITabBarDelegate` properly. Check the code where you instantiate the `UITabBar` and be sure that you've set the appDelegate to be the delegate of the tabbar.

Comment: I am using the default UITabBarApplication. Can I connect the two in interface builder? If not how would I set the AppDelegate to be the delegate of the tabbar?

Comment: BTW: Your awesome, you know that?

Comment: @TheHAWK: I don't use the IB much, so not sure about that. To do it programmatically isn't hard, though. Post your code for the app delegate where you define the tabbar and I may be able to help. All you'll need to do is add the line `[tabbar setDelegate:self];` in the appropriate place within the `AppDelegate.m` file, probably in `– application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

Comment: This is what I have in my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions now:
    [self.window addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self.tabBarController setDelegate:self];  - and it still dont work

Comment: That snippet you suggested says that tabbar is unidentified. Did you mean:  [self.tabBarController setDelegate:self]; ?